# Changing Android source in ViewGroup.java

Tags: java, android, android-source

I want to make some changes in one function in ViewGroup.java. I already had the sources compiled, so I am only compilling the part that I changed last, with the command

```
make framework
```

but when I start the emulator, it crashes with the error

```
--------- beginning of crash
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime: *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing class when invoking static main com.android.server.SystemServer
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.invokeStaticMain(RuntimeInit.java:205)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.applicationInit(RuntimeInit.java:326)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.zygoteInit(RuntimeInit.java:278)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.handleSystemServerProcess(ZygoteInit.java:458)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.startSystemServer(ZygoteInit.java:545)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.server.SystemServer
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.invokeStaticMain(RuntimeInit.java:203)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 5 more
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.server.SystemServer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/services.jar", zip file "/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar", zip file "/system/framework/wifi-service.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 8 more
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /system/framework/services.jar
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:295)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:279)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makePathElements(DexPathList.java:248)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:120)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:38)
01-29 22:22:30.570   280   280 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.handleSystemServerProcess(ZygoteInit.java:451)
```

Does this means that I can't change this file? Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: *Is there a way to do this?* make your own android OS build and install it on the device that's the only way

Comment: @Selvin How can I do that? Since I was modifying the sources I thought I was doing that.

Comment: @Selvin oh sorry... I forgot to mention that I already had the sources compiled. Now I am only compiling the part that I changed last. I will edit the question

Comment: first of all *I want to make some changes in one function in ViewGroup.java* ...  in custom ROM? if no, then you can't

Comment: @Selvin yes, but when I run the emulator that is available when the build is finished I receive that error

Comment: Interesting how did you install your custom ROM on your emulator? **I bet you didn't do this**... you just compile framework and compile your code against it ... but framework used for compilation doesn't fit the runtime on device/emulator so using it doesn't make sens

Comment: @Selvin Do I need to compile the sources in general again?

Comment: `make` the whole source tree and see if it works.

Comment: @Onik I did that and it worked. Thanks